# Double Database Queries

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Some of My code:

```
u = User.query.filter_by(username=requested_username.lower()).first()


teamie = Team.query.filter_by(name=requested_team)
team = teamie.filter_by(user_id=u.id).first()
```

^what am I doing wrong? (it's not working - but I don't know why 
Also is there anyway to combine the two team-related lines into one line?

Comment: What do you mean for "not working"? I've not been using sqlalchemy for a while, but it seems correct to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on some of the rest of your sqlalchemy setup, but if I guess at your setup, I think this might do the trick:

```
u = User.filter_by(User.username==requested_username.lower()).first()

teamie = Team.filter_by(Team.name==requested_team)\
             .filter_by(Team.user_id==u.id).first()
```

Here's an explanation: First, in your filter_by statements, you need a double equals sign "==" not just "=". Also, it's actually the session object that has a query method, not the model itself, so you didn't need query unless you used it like this (I'm assuming your sesssion object is actually called session):

```
u = session.query(User).filter_by(User.username==requested_username.lower()).first()

teamie = session.query(Team).filter_by(Team.name==requested_team)\
                            .filter_by(Team.user_id==u.id).first()
```

Finally, most often you need model.column syntax in your filter statements. Hope that sheds some light.

Comment: `filter()` and `filter_by()` are two different things. `filter_by()` accepts keyword parameters, `filter()` uses SQLAlchemy expressions like `Team.name==requested_team`. See the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by).

Comment: Why is double equals necessary? The docs seems to say otherwise: http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/queries.html